# [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager ] Datasource name not found and no device driver specified

Tags: oracle, ms-access, migration, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to open a Access db in oracle Sql developer. For the same I have added Microsoft access driver for both 32 and 64 bit at ODBC datasource administrator.

Now, while opening the Access file in SQL Developer tool, I am getting below error.

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager ] Datasource name not found and no device driver specified
```

Please help.

Comment: I don't think you can open a MS-Access Database (a contradiction in terms) with SQL Developer.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit dont be so sarcastic about Access. it is a Database. And you are wrong, it is possible to connect to it from SQL Developer, [official doc here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/ms-access-connection-viewlet-swf-086613.html)

Comment: @Lara have you tried with the method explained in my link above? Basically you select the database file directly, instead of a DNS entry in the ODBC panel.

Comment: @ThomasG Followed the Video and tried to establish the connection but got the same error as stated in the post. Is there something, I should try to get of it ?